# MRJob - Python - How to return null when division is 0/value

Tags: python, mrjob

How can I modify this code so when senti_avg is not divisible (0/value), reducer() outputs NULL or NONE instead of crashing?

```
def reducer(self, bs_id, value):
    avg_data = list(value)
    senti_sum = sum([a[0] for a in avg_data])
    word_sum = sum([a[1] for a in avg_data])
    senti_avg = senti_sum/float(word_sum)

    yield (bs_id, senti_avg)
```

Comment: I think you meant `value/0` perhaps?

Comment: value/0 makes sense, but my word_count is always > 0, maybe there is an error with my code. Don't know why it is returning error for 0/value...

Comment: Perhaps; if `avg_data` is empty, both `senti_sum` and `word_sum` would be 0, leading to `0/0` and a `ZeroDivisionError`.

Answer (score 4):

You use [python exception handling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

```
try:
    senti_avg = senti_sum/float(word_sum)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    senti_avg = None
```